# jQuery submit "li" item to form

Tags: forms, submission

i have this form which i would like to submit once a user selects a list item within the search bar. the search bar is here dev.twinsourcesupply.com

I can't seem to figure out how to attach a jquery release or onclick handler to process the submit functionality to the submit button. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's my form code below.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery#submit():

```
$('#your-form').submit();
```

Comment: this is what i have currently

 <code>
  $('.suggestionList.li').onclick(function() {
   $('form#quicksearch').submit();
  });
 });</code>

but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @user2134175 Did you put action attribute in your form? If it is still not working, you may need to use manual ajax call...